# Is it possible to force k8s worker to use specific GPU only?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, multi-gpu

I have a on-premise k8s GPU cluster with several computing nodes which have 8 GPUs respectively. Because we are on the way of migration to k8s, and also there are some remained project to use GPUs, I have to remain some GPUs which do not allowed by k8s to use. Furthermore, some projects require the use of contiguous GPUs(I mean, using a physically adjacent PCIE bus), so it is necessary to leave those GPUs specific.

So the question is, is it possible to force k8s worker to use specific GPU only? For example, I would like to configure my k8s worker to allocate GPUs from 0 to 4 and GPUs from 4 to 7 cannot be allocated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Answer (score 1):

if you want your jobs to never use one of the gpu nodes, you can taint this nodes with noschedule taint
for example:

```
kubectl taint nodes aks-gpuv100small.. no=k8s:NoSchedule
```

if you want your jobs to run only on specific gpu nodes you can add labels to this nodes and nodeSelectors to your jobs

```
 kubectl label nodes aks-gpuv100small.. k8s=gpu
 nodeSelector:
   k8s: gpu
```

if you want inside a gpu node to only expose some of the devices to the job you can add the following environment variable to your job

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be up to the specifics of your device plugin, and if you mean the Nvidia one, I don't think so, at least not without some custom work. The https://github.com/NVIDIA/go-gpuallocator library does support modular allocation policies, but I don't think this is specifically exposed as an option in the device plugin. It doesn't really have much in the way of configuration at all. But you could fork it and go to town.